# multiple sliders, combined navigation

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm working with the jquery easy slider 1.7 and got a little issue here.
I'm trying to get multiple sliders on my webpage, which are all controlled by one single navigation. The problem is, every new slider that I create, brings it own navigation. Is there any way to combine these navigations?

I'm not very familiar with javascript, so it would be great if anybody could help me with this one.

I'm using the numeric navigation so I guess I got to change or add something here:

```
if(options.numeric){
for(var i=0;i<s;i++){
    $(document.createElement("li"))
        .attr('id',options.numericId + (i+1))
        // THIS LINE:
        .html('<a rel='+ i +' href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ slideName[i] +'</a>')
        .appendTo($("#"+ options.numericId))
        .click(function(){
            animate($("a",$(this)).attr('rel'),true);
         });

};      
        } else {
            $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){     
                animate("next",true);
            });
            $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){     
                animate("prev",true);               
            }); 
            $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){        
                animate("first",true);
            });             
            $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){     
                animate("last",true);               
            });             
        };
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have a web address? or a jsfiddle, or something? Each slider that is created has at least one attribute that makes it unique to the others. It'd be nice to see what you're working with before offering a way to help.

Comment: sure, here it is:

http://tinyurl.com/bub7byg

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit the core script to change the functionality. Use the params that are available. Right now, all of your slider controls have the same ID. It's not throwing an error, but it doesn't surprise me that it's not working.

If you haven't gotten one slider to work, do that first.

If so, then make sure the params you use include unique IDs (if you must use that param):

```
$("#slider").easySlider({ 
    numericId: 'navi1'
})
$("#slider2").easySlider({
    numericId: 'navi2'
})
```

Take another look at the source code of the examples too: http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/05.html. There are two independent sliders there.